# How to use Stream to get all Lists from a nested List that match a specific condition?

Tags: java, list, java-stream, nested-lists

How can I achieve the same logic in my code using only Streams, without the `for` loop as shown in my code below?

I have tried using `flatMap`, but I get stuck on the condition part, since `allMatch()` only returns a `boolean`.

How can I retrieve all the rows from the nested `ArrayList` that passes the condition without using `for` loop?

```java
ArrayList<ArrayList<Tile>> completeRows = new ArrayList<>();
for (ArrayList<Tile> rows: getGridTiles()) {
    if (rows.stream().allMatch(p -> p.getOccupiedBlockType() != BlockType.EMPTY)) {
        completeRows.add(rows);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply `filter()` with a nested stream (*exactly the same as you've used as a condition in your code*) passed to it as a `Predicate` to verify that a list consists of only *non-empty* tiles.

And then collect all the lists (*rows*) that have passed the *predicate* into a List using `collect()`.

```
public static List<List<Tile>> getNonEmptyRows(List<List<Tile>> rows) {
    
    return rows.stream()
        .filter(row -> row.stream().allMatch(tile -> tile.getOccupiedBlockType() != BlockType.EMPTY))
        .collect(Collectors.toList()); // or .toList() with Java 16+
}
```

> I have tried using `flatMap`

You need to use `flatMap` when your goal is to flatten the steam of collections (*or objects holding a reference to a collection*) to a stream of elements of these collections. In these case, turn a stream of lists of tiles `Stream<List<Tile>>` into a stream of tiles `Stream<Tile>`.

Judging by your code, it's not you what you want because you're accumulating the *rows* (lists of tiles) into another list and not *"flattening"* them.

But just in case, that's how it can be done:

```
public static List<Tile> getNonEmptyTiles(List<List<Tile>> rows) {
    
    return rows.stream()
        .filter(row -> row.stream().allMatch(tile -> tile.getOccupiedBlockType() != BlockType.EMPTY))
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toList()); // or .toList() with Java 16+
}
```

*Sidenote:* leverage abstract data types - write your code against interfaces. [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface)